# Updating Multiple Select Values via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JS to update the selected value of multiple `select` elements, at the same time. For some reason, my JS only updates one `select`, not all of them on the page. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the `id` attribute of the `select`, and the various `select` elements need to have the same `id`.

How might I change the function so that *ALL* drop downs with id 'dropdown-test' are updated?

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('dropdown-test').value="3";
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown_test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown_test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You must have unique IDs, not same id for different elements

Comment: "the various selects need to have the same `id`." - if this is true, you have a requirement that means you'll be doing HTML all wrong. The whole point of Id's is that they are unique within a page!

Comment: Also, your `getElementById()` call is passed a different ID than the one the DOM elements have.

Comment: Try jQuery, put a `class` of `dropdown_test` to the `<select>`s and use `$(".dropdown_test").val(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#strings option[value=Test]').attr('selected', true);
```

**[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McddQ/4/)** with similar `ids`

Answer (score 3):

You must have unique IDs. 
If you want to use **jQuery** you can do like this:

```
$('select').val(3);
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/78pEj/)**

If you want to use **plain javascript** you can use:

```
var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
    all_select[i].value = 3;
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pzA9y/)**

If you need ids anyway, please give them different names.

**Read [about ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687):**

Comment: +1 Note though the OP specifically says the only constraint is that the `id` cannot be changed and must be the same for all elements, even though that is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

try using class name.Id should be unique.

**HTML**

```
<select class="dropdown_test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

<select class="dropdown_test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementByClass('.dropdown-test').value="3";
```